# How to light liquid on fire?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to simulate liquid being lit on fire, but only the fluid works when I simulate both domains (the fire domain is on the second layer).  I tried to find a tutorial for this, but wasn't able to.  I've attached the .blend.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: the .blend doesn't seem to have linked properly. Try baking the fluid to a mesh and then use that as the fire emitter. Otherwise you are trying to simulate from a simulation which doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to load the .blend.  I do intend to use the mesh as an emitter but I want the match to be on fire first before it touches the fluid.

Comment: You will need to have two separate emitters

Comment: The issue is more why the match won't light on fire at all.  I could use the fluid as an emitter as well but I really need the match to light first.

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  I just had to remove the smoke modifier in the physics panel and reset all the values again.  Not sure why that helped.  And yes, definitely the fluid works as an emitter! :)